# Filtering non-exploded structure in SPARK Data Frame with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have:

```
 +-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
 |cities                 |name   |schools                             |
 +-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
 |[palo alto, menlo park]|Michael|[[stanford, 2010], [berkeley, 2012]]|
 |[santa cruz]           |Andy   |[[ucsb, 2011]]                      |
 |[portland]             |Justin |[[berkeley, 2014]]                  |
 +-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

I get this no sweat:

```
 val res = df.select ("*").where (array_contains (df("schools.sname"), "berkeley")).show(false)
```

But without wanting to explode or using an UDF, I in the same way or similar as above, how can I do something like:

```
 return all rows where at least 1 schools.sname starts with "b"  ?
```

e.g.:

```
 val res = df.select ("*").where (startsWith (df("schools.sname"), "b")).show(false)
```

This is wrong of course, just to demonstrate the point. But how can I do something like this without exploding or UDF-usage returning true/false or whatever and filtering in general without UDF usage? May be it is not possible. I cannot find any such examples. Or is it **expr** I need?

Answers gotten which show how certain things have a certain approach as some capabilities do not exist in SCALA. I read an article that points out to new array features to be implemented after this, so proves a point.

Comment: @Leo C  I am wondering if you could shed some light on this by any chance?

Comment: how did you name it as "schools.sname" when creating the DF?

Comment: @stack0114106  Inferred via spark.read.json - that is all correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

```
scala> val df = Seq ( ( Array("palo alto", "menlo park"), "Michael", Array(("stanford", 2010), ("berkeley", 2012))),
     |     (Array(("santa cruz")),"Andy",Array(("ucsb", 2011))),
     |       (Array(("portland")),"Justin",Array(("berkeley", 2014)))
     |     ).toDF("cities","name","schools")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cities: array<string>, name: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val df2 = df.select ("*").withColumn("sch1",df("schools._1"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cities: array<string>, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> val df3=df2.select("*").withColumn("sch2",concat_ws(",",df2("sch1")))
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [cities: array<string>, name: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> df3.select("*").where( df3("sch2") rlike "^b|,b" ).show(false)
+-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|cities                 |name   |schools                             |sch1                |sch2             |
+-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|[palo alto, menlo park]|Michael|[[stanford, 2010], [berkeley, 2012]]|[stanford, berkeley]|stanford,berkeley|
|[portland]             |Justin |[[berkeley, 2014]]                  |[berkeley]          |berkeley         |
+-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

in one more step, you can drop the unwanted columns.

Comment: OK, the reality is that with the functions I was thinking about, it was not possible. I answered a question with rlike yesterday BTW.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this qualifies as a UDF or not, but you could define a new filter function. If using a `Dataset[Student]` where:

```
case class School(sname: String, year: Int)
case class Student(cities: Seq[String], name: String, schools: Seq[School])
```

Then you can simply do the following:

```
students
    .filter(
        r => r.schools.filter(_.sname.startsWith("b")).size > 0)
```

However, if you are just using a `DataFrame` then:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

students.toDF
    .filter(
        r => r.getAs[Seq[Row]]("schools").filter(_.getAs[String]("name")
                                         .startsWith("b")).size > 0)
```

Both of which will result in:

```
+-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|cities                 |name   |schools                             |
+-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
|[palo alto, menlo park]|Michael|[[stanford, 2010], [berkeley, 2012]]|
|[portland]             |Justin |[[berkeley, 2014]]                  |
+-----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Welcome. I was looking for the select style with functions as opposed to (r => r etc. But OK, this seems to prove at least that that approach is most likely not possible and I was not missing something in that regard. I will wait and see if @Leo C comes back, otherwise the marks will go to you for the answer as well as the upvote now. Thx